# What is my rogue's Stealth modifier?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, rogue, stealth

What is my rogue's Stealth modifier?

Here's my attempt to calculate it:

- My Dexterity modifier is +4.
- I have proficiency in Stealth and Dex saving throws, so I think
  that’s another +4 (+2 and +2).
- Then I have Expertise; I’m not sure whether it will double my
  proficiency in Stealth to make my total Stealth bonus a +10, or
  double both my saving throw proficiency and my Stealth proficiency to
  make my total Stealth bonus a +12.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Take the [tour]. You may want to see these related questions: [What is the difference between skill- and save-specific modifiers and the Proficiency bonus?](/questions/53726), [Do you add your proficiency bonus if you are not proficient in the skill but you are proficient in the stat?](/questions/73292)

Comment: Level of your character would help.

Comment: To determine your proficiency bonus we need to know your level. It appears from the question that you are level 1-4, is that correct?

Answer (score 29):

### Your total Stealth mod is +8.

Your mistake here is that you are adding your proficiency with Dexterity **saving throws** to your total. This is incorrect. **Saving throws** are a special kind of die roll, separate from the (related) **ability check** and **attack roll**. Saving throws are generally reactionary; the DM will ask you to make one in response to certain kinds of threats. Skills are used proactively, that is, generally the DM will call for a ability check when you are trying to accomplish something.

Stealth is a skill. Thus, to calculate the corresponding modifier for Stealth checks, you will apply the related ability modifier (for Stealth, the corresponding ability is Dexterity; your Dex mod is +4, as you stated) and your proficiency bonus (if you are proficient; at level 1, this is +2). Since you chose Stealth as one of the skills you have Expertise in, this last number is doubled.

Thus, when you make a Stealth check, you roll a d20 and add:
**+4 (Dex) + [+2 (Proficient) * 2 (Expertise)]**
for a total of **+8**.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that (afaik) you never combine the proficiency bonus from 2 different sources on a roll.

Comment: @fabian: Not relevant here, but Xanathar's suggests (and the OneD&D playtest rules specifically recommend) granting advantage in cases where two different sources of proficiency apply. e.g. Xanathar's suggests advantage on Stealth checks on wood flooring if you have proficiency in Carpenter's Tools (your know enough about wood construction to avoid squeaky floorboards). OneD&D made Sleight of Hand usable for lockpicking (previously only Thieves' Tools Proficiency applied to lockpicking); having Sleight of Hand and Thieves' Tools Prof would mean perma-advantage. Not *additive*, still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You did not state your level, so I will work with lvl 1-4.

When you make a Stealth attempt, roll d20, add proficiency (+2)and add DEX modifier (+4). Then Expertise allows you to add your proficiency again. This adds up to a total of +8 to your roll.

Any bonus to Saving Throws does not apply.